# What is the order of execution of "SELECT" To "ORDER BY"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a sql which is:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM 
Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC;
```

I dont know the sequence of how execution goes in order from Select to OrderBy.So,i gave number as 1,2,3,4 to get the sequence of execution. So,I think:

```
SELECT 
(4)COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM 
Customers
(1)GROUP BY Country
(2)HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5
(3)ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC;
```

Is,it right or wrong?If,I am wrong please correct it.

Comment: `select` -> `group by` (sometimes both these steps can happen simultaneously, if MySQL decides to do a loose index scan) -> `having` (filters out the grouped data based on condition) -> `order by` (sorts it)

Comment: See the execution plan.
(1) Stream aggregate: COUNT(CustomerID) grouped by Country
 -> maps to SELECTed (specified) columns and GROUP BY clause
(2) Filter: COUNT(CustomerID) > 5
 -> maps to HAVING
(3) Sort: COUNT(CustomerID)
 -> maps to ORDER BY